# How to get more customer sources using Stripe NodeJS SDK?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am able to get customer sources only 1st 10 via get customer API:

```
# stripe.customers.retrieve

{
  "id": "cus_DE8HSMZ75l2Dgo",
  ...
  "sources": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_DE8HSMZ75l2Dgo/sources"
  },
  ...
}
```

But how do I get more? Is the only way via an AJAX call? I was thinking there should be a function somewhere in the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve a Customer object via the API, Stripe will return the `sources` property which is a List object. The `data` property will be an array with up to 10 sources in it.

If you want the ability to get more sources than the 10 most recent ones, you will need to use [Pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pagination). The idea is that you will first get a list of N objects (10 by default). Then you will request the next "page" from Stripe by asking for N objects again but using the parameter `starting_after` set to the id of the last object in the previous page. You will continue doing that until the `has_more` property in the page returned is `false` indicating you retrieved all the objects.

For example if your Customer has 35 sources, you would get the first page (10), then call list to get 10 more (20), then 10 more again (30) and then the last call would return only 5 sources (35) and `has_more` would be false.

To decrease the number of calls, you can also set `limit` to a higher value. The maximum value is 100 in that case.

Here's what the code would look like:

```
// list those cards 3 at a time
var listOptions = {limit: 3};
while(1) {
    var sources = await stripe.customers.listSources(
      customer.id,
      listOptions
    );

    var nbSourcesRetrieved = sources.data.length;
    var lastSourceId = sources.data[nbSourcesRetrieved - 1].id;
    console.log("Received " + nbSourcesRetrieved + " - last source: " + lastSourceId + " - has_more: " + sources.has_more);

    // Leave if we are done with pagination
    if(sources.has_more == false) {
      break;
    }

    // Store the last source id in the options for the next page
    listOptions['starting_after'] = lastSourceId;
}
```

You can see a full running example on Runkit here: https://runkit.com/5a6b26c0e3908200129fbb5d/5b49eabda462940012c33880

Comment: But this uses the listCards API, in my understanding cards and sources are different?

Comment: @JiewMeng you can simply use `listSources` instead, I just updated the example.

Answer (score 2):

As of stripe-node 6.11.0, you may auto-paginate list methods, including customer sources. Stripe provides a few different APIs for this to aid with a variety of node versions and styles.

See the docs [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#auto-pagination)

The important part to notice is **.autoPagingEach**:

```
await stripe.customers.listSources({ limit: 100 }).autoPagingEach(async (source) => {
  doSomethingWithYourSource(source)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look into the [sources](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/resources/Customers.js) of the stripe-node package, it seems there is a `stripe.customers.listSources` method, which takes a `customerId` as parameter and requests to the correct url. I suppose it works similar to the [`listCards` method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#list_cards). But I couldn't find it in the docs, so you have to treat it as an undocumented feature ... But maybe it's just an error in the docs. You could contact the support about it. We used stripe in an old project and they appreciated any input on their documentation.