# Why is saved stripe card only in sources and not cards?

Tags: stripe-payments

I saved my credit card in Stripe but why is it only in sources

[image]

And not under cards?

[image]

I have used `stripe.customers.createSource` as specified in the docs to save a card (https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card)

I guess this is the reason why `stripe.customers.listCards` return nothing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `stripe.customers.createSource` in the library is just making a POST request to `/v1/customers/cus_123/sources` to add a source to it. The type of the source itself depends on what you have used to create it client-side.

If you create card [Tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) client-side `tok_123` you will get [Card object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object) `card_123` on the customer. You could also get a [Bank Account object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_bank_account_object) if you use ACH debits in the US and created a bank account tokens `btok_123`. This is the legacy method that has existed for years in the API.

More recently, Stripe release a new high-level object called a [Source](https://stripe.com/docs/api#source_object) and your can read more about Sources in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/sources). This allows you to have one unique object no matter the payment method used (card, SEPA debit, Alipay, Sofort, etc.). This makes handling the logic in your code a lot easier as the objects have the same shape and properties specific to each payment method live in a sub-hash that you know to handle differently. Those Source objects have an id in the format `src_123`.

Here, your customer has Sources attached to it. This means that client-side, when you collect the card details, you are actively creating a Source instead of a Token. This is due to the methods/calls you use to create it. In [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) you would be using [createSource()](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-source) instead of [createToken()](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-token) while in the mobile SDKs they would create Sources by default.

Ultimately, Sources are a better approach for a new integration as they are more scalable and can handle the growth of your business internationally in the future. I'd recommend keeping Sources moving forward.

Comment: Ah ic, so if I want to allow customers to get a list of cards (`source.owner.type == 'card' and source.owner.usage == 'reusable'`) they can pay by, I should use [`stripe.customer.listSources`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51335851/292291)? But it appears undocumented. Is that the correct way?

Comment: Oh but isit possible to filter them down to reusable card sources by default? I think its more efficient than having to filter out the unnecessary stuff myself and handle all the pagination

Comment: @JiewMeng the type of the source is at the top level, not under `owner`. It's documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#source_object-type It's also not possible to only list re-usable sources today though you can simply detach single use sources after their use instead: https://stripe.com/docs/api#detach_source